# Calculating the elements of $H_1(G)$ for a graph

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I know how to calculate the generating edges for $H_1(G)$ for a simple, connected graph (1-simplex) $G$. However, once I have these generators, how do I calculate the remaining group elements? From what I've read, I'm pretty sure these elements have the form $[a] + B$, i.e. they are cosets of the boundary group, but I'm still unsure how to translate this into an explicit enumeration of all elements. How would I do the calculation for the following graph? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: What is homology to you? Simplicial homology? Also, choosing a spanning tree is helpful.

Comment: Yes, simplicial homology. I am able to get the generating edges via a spanning tree, but I wasn't sure how to go from those edges to a full enumeration of the group.